# how can i write if else condition in HTML or HTML5 not using javascript

Tags: html

If the variable is available i have to display the tag else don't want to render the line of tag.

how to write if condition in html ? i have written below code but its not working

```
 <html>
    <body><table>
       <IF ${mobile} != null > <tr> <td>Mobile</td> <td>${mobile}</td> </tr> <ENDIF>
</table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I don't want to use javascript is there any possible way to write in html only.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write conditional logic in HTML; it is a [**markup** language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language), not a [programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language).

Answer (score 0):

You can't write conditional statements in html, the best you can do is using a template engine like handlebars, similar to html with additional conditional and loops